# "Decorators" around Jupyter Notebook cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm curious about whether it's possible to configure Jupyter Notebook/Lab to run code "around" the cells, in the similar fashion as decorators do. A concrete example:

Say I have a cell with some code:

```
[some code]
```

What I'd like to do is to log if this code raises an exception. So I could achieve it with the following:

```
try:
    [some code]
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception()
    raise e
```

Ideally I'd like to do this globally for each cell, without the need to explicitly write the try-except clause each time.

This is useful, for example, if I run something that takes a long time to finish. This way I can close the notebook, and it will keep running in the background, but if it fails, I'll be able to debug it using the logged traceback.

Comment: There's a few related options. Say you only wanted this feature for a few cells. You could define a custom cell magic command. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cell-magic-to-save-image-output-as-a-png-file/11906/2?u=fomightez) for a concrete example. If you want this on all cells though you want to either make an extension that can do this in your Jupyter. Or use nbformat or jupytext (or a combination) to inject your logging code, execute the notebook on the command line and then remove the logging code it added in the final notebook, unless you want to leave it there. I think  ...

Comment: <continuted> you could get a way with an easier thing though by changing up your workflow. You can execute entire notebooks on the command line with papermill and according to [what I wrote here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/executenb-monitor-cell-execution-stdout-stream-asynchronously/3069/2?u=fomightez) it saves each cell's result as it runs. (`jupyter nbconvert` that also enables executing entire notebooks on the command line seems to only write the file when completed. I haven't check or seen mention of what Jupytext, which also allows command line execution of notbeooks, does in ...

Comment: <continued> this regard.) So with papermill updating a notebook as it goes, ideally you could trigger a notebook to start running via the command line where you use screen or tmux session to run it where you can send it to the background/detach and then monitor the running notebook from inside Jupyter every now and then.